# LLVM , -fprofile-instr-generate , Undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, instrumentation

I am facing following error with "-fprofile-instr-generate".
Appreciate your inputs to resolve this error

Thanks,

**Error:**

```
clang++ -O2 -fprofile-instr-generate hello.cpp
/tmp/hello-58ef5f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-58ef5f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-58ef5f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-58ef5f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-58ef5f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_runtime_user: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_runtime'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Clang version:** clang version 3.5.0

**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04

**LD version:**GNU gold (GNU Binutils 2.24.51.20140522) 1.11

**LLVM Configure options:** configure --enable-profiling --enable-optimized --enable-shared --disable-debug-runtime --enable-targets=all --prefix=/install --with-binutils-include=/gold_linker/binutils/include

**Above error says , 'use -v'. Output of -v is as follows**

```
 "/usr/local/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -L/home/LLVM_install/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/hello-c8552f.o /home/LLVM_install/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.profile-x86_64.a -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/hello-c8552f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-c8552f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-c8552f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-c8552f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_init: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_register_function'
/tmp/hello-c8552f.o:hello.cpp:function __llvm_profile_runtime_user: error: undefined reference to '__llvm_profile_runtime'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm wondering whether it's related to these functions being renamed in http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140317/101771.html.

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not occour if you use cmake to build llvm and compiler-rt.
But, if you use configure while building llvm and compiler-rt then this issue occurs.

```
#Step-1) Build your LLVM compiler as follows
cd /home/user
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
cd llvm/tools
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
cd ../../
mkdir build_folder
cd build_folder
cmake /home/user/llvm
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/llvm_install /home/user/llvm
make 
make install

#Step-2) Build compiler-rt as follows. Use llvm-config from your llvm installation from above step-1
git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git
mkdir comp_rt_build_dir
cd comp_rt_build_dir
cmake ../compiler-rt -DLLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/llvm-config
make 
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you need to pass that flag at the linker stage too. To quote [the docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html):

> If linking with the clang driver, pass -fprofile-instr-generate to the link stage to make sure the necessary runtime libraries are linked in.

Try `-Wl,-fprofile-instr-generate`.